# Parsing a string to double

Tags: vb.net

I am having some trouble with a program I'm creating. I need to take some doubles out of a .txt file. I have gotten the program to read the .txt file and store individual lines in a string as I need, but `MyDouble = Double.Parse(String)` crashes my program with message:

```
Input string was not in a correct format
```

and `MyDouble = Double.TryParse(String, Boolean)` doesn't return anything to the MyDouble.

I tried using a Try-Catch statement around what is throwing `System.FormatException`, and as expected, it did the same as `Double.TryParse()`.

Comment: Can you give an example of the input file?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Also study the Intellisense help that appears as you type your code.

Comment: The error message is telling you that the string in not in the correct format, it is not a double. Check the text file for empty lines or lines that do not contain doubles, or contain additional characters.

Comment: Also, your `TryParse` call is incorrect. Check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This is not a chat board.  Questions posted are intended to help others with the same problem, so defacing your question after you get an answer is not allowed.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] and always search before asking.